# How to express the "not equals" relation in linear programming?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I want to solve a LP problem in Python with the library Pulpe (or any other).

I want to express a constraint stating that all my variables must have different values, (their domain is {0, 1, 2, 3... N} for a given integer N.) that is `x_1 != x_2 != x_3 ... != x_N`.

The solver gives me a solution when I do not add any constraint related to what I mentionned above but when I do, it tells me that the system is not feasible even though it has one solution.

In order to add the "all different" constraint, I did the following:

```
for x_i in variables:
    for x_j in variables:
        if the following constraint has not been already added and x_i != x_j:
            my_problem += x_i - x_j >= 1, "unique name for the constraint"
```

The previous code does not work. When I want to add the constraint `x_i != x_j`, it just doesn't work. So, as I am working with a bounded set of integers, I can (I think) rewrite the "not equals" as x_i - x_j > 0. Pulpe tells me that it does not handle the ">" operator between `int` and `LpAffineExpression` so I wrote `x_i - x_j >= 1`. However, it runs but it seems that it does not work and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways of doing this, depending on the exact situation.

You seem to have `n` variables `x[i]`. They can assume values `{0,...,n}` and must be all different.

As an aside: your notation `x[1] ≠ x[2] ≠ x[3]..` is not completely correct. E.g. `x[1]=1, x[2]=2, x[3]=1` would satisfy `x[1] ≠ x[2] ≠ x[3]`.

The all-different constraint can be written pairwise as `x[i] ≠ x[j]` for all `i < j` (we don't want to check `i` and `j` twice). This inequality can be restated as: `x[i] ≤ x[j]-1 OR x[i] ≥ x[j]+1`. The OR condition can be implemented in a MIP model as:

```
 x[i] ≤ x[j]-1 + M δ[i,j]        ∀ i < j
 x[i] ≥ x[j]+1 - M (1-δ[i,j])    ∀ i < j
 δ[i,j] ∈ {0,1}
```

where `M=n+1`. We added extra binary variables `δ[i,j]`.

This is the most direct formulation of a "not-equal" construct. It also has relatively few binary variables: about n^2/2. Other formulations are also possible. For more information see [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/05/all-different-and-mixed-integer.html).

Note that constraint programming solvers often have built-in facilities for the all-different constraint, so it may be easier to use a CP solver (they can also be more efficient for models with all-different constraints).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your constraint does not work is that you are requiring `x_i` to be at least 1 greater than `x_j`, for every `i` and `j`. So you are requiring `x_1 > x_2` and `x_2 > x_1`. You can probably fix this issue by replacing `x_i != x_j` with `i > j` or something like that, in your `if` statement.

But in your case, I would consider using binary variables to indicate which value each `x_i` takes. For example, let `y_{i,n} = 1` if `x_i = n`. Then you have a constraint like

`sum {i=1,...,N} y_{i,n} <= 1` for all `n = 0,...,N`

(i.e., each value of `n` can be used at most once) and another like

`sum {n=0,...,N} y_{i,n} = 1` for all `i = 1,...,N`

(every `i` must be assigned some value `n`).

Then, in your formulation, replace all the `x_i` variables with `sum {n=0,...,N} y_{i,n}`.